# How to escape double quotes in an if else + concatenate formula

Tags: excel

I kept looking on the web but seems that no one is asking about this scenario:

This is for an `IF ELSE` + `CONCATENATE` formula, which both uses double quotes.

To simplify its look, I will put "haha" and "hehe" instead of the actual texts that I need.

[image]

**First, here's my `IF ELSE` formula**

`=IF(F4="multi","haha","hehe")`

This will work perfectly.

But If I try to insert my `CONCATENATE` formula inside the `IF ELSE`, it won't, which is this:

`="The 2020 amendment by ch. "&(B3)&", effective "&TEXT(D3,"mmmm, d, yyyy")&", "`

The output should look like this "**The 2020 amendment by ch. 1, effective August, 31, 2020,**"

Now if I try to combine both, it should be like this:

`=IF(F4="multi","="The 2020 amendment by ch. "&(B3)&", effective "&TEXT(D3,"mmmm, d, yyyy")&", "","hehe")`

So now there's an invalid double quotes inside the `IF ELSE` formula. I'm sure a lot of professionals in Excel out there knows the workaround for this but I don't. Please help me understand this.

Comment: you don't need the second `=`. You could do `=IF(F4="multi","The 2020 a...."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error.  The `=` should be only at the beginning of the formula.

```
=IF(F4="multi","The 2020 amendment by ch. "&(B3)&", effective "&TEXT(D3,"mmmm, d, yyyy")&", ","hehe")
```